# Optional Path parameters in AWS APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am started to work on APIGateway for writing rest API using SAM template.

I have a endpoint as "example.com", here I need to have path param as optional parameter; 
ex: www.example.com/user/{optional_Parameter}/

When I tried to hit the above URL without giving parameter it shows 403 Forbidden Error.

Referred few docs, however no luck.  If anyone achieved in API Gateway please do share the workaround to achieve having Optional path parameter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve it is to define both `www.example.com/user/` and `www.example.com/user/{optional_Parameter}/` as endpoints in your API gateway.

Comment: Just to be clear this is not the easiest way. Unfortunately API Gateway will only create a resource for one or another, whichever is being created later